# Spring-Mass System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A spring-mass system has a spring constant of $\displaystyle\frac{3N}{m}$.  A mass of $2$ kg is attached to the spring, and the motion takes place in a viscous fluid that offers a resistance numerically equal to the magnitude of the instantaneous velocity.  If the system is driven by an external force of $(3\cos(t)-2\sin(3t))$ N, determine the steady-state response.

---

My study group came up with the following.  Is this reasonable?

$$\begin{align}
&k= \displaystyle\frac{3N}{m}\\
&m=\displaystyle\frac{2k}{g}\\
&2y''+ry'+3y=3\cos(3t)-2\sin(3t)
\end{align}$$

How do I find $r$?

Comment: $r$ measures the resistance, right? which is "numerically equal to the magnitude of the instantaneous velocity", right? and the instantaneous velocity is $y'$, right?

Comment: It would be better to write $k= \displaystyle 3\frac{N}{m}$ and definitely to write $m=2\ kg$ as the first makes the units clear and the second get the k and g in the same place.

Comment: By the way, I think the symbol $m$ is being used for two different things here. I think $N/m$ stands for newtons per meter, while $m=2{\rm\ kg}$ (and not $m=2k/g$) means mass is two kilograms. But perhaps I misunderstand.

Answer (score 1):

$ry'$ is the resistance, which the problem states is equal to the magnitude of the instantaneous velocity.  you should understand the differential equation:  the $y''$ term is $F=ma$ a la newton.  the $y'$ term is some force proportional to the velocity, like a resistance, the $y$ term is a force proportional to the displacement, i.e. the spring, and the non-homogeneous term is a driving force.  anyway, i believe the problem is saying that $r=1$

Comment: How do we draw the conclusion that 1 is equal to r?  We don't have a function for the velocity.

Comment: Yes, we do: $y$ is displacement, so (as I suggested in my original comment) $y'$ is velocity.

Answer (score 1):

"a resistance numerically equal to the magnitude of the instantaneous velocity"

Isn't the text saying that $r=1$ ?